# Save data from google info window with php

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have tried searching this site as I am sure I am not the first to ask this. I have put a map on my site and want users to add markers and info. This is working fine but the info is not saving. When you click the save and close button nothing happens. Please could someone tell me where I am going wrong. Here is the html code

var marker;
    var infowindow;

```
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.532226,31.290586);
  var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Posted by:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Time +/-:</td> <td><input type='text' id='time'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Sighting:</td> <td><select id='sighting'>" +
             "<option value='Lion' SELECTED>Lion</option>" +
             "<option value='Rhino'>Rhino</option>" +
             "<option value='Elephant'>Elephant</option>" +
             "<option value='Buffalo'>Buffalo</option>" +
             "<option value='Leopard'>Leopard</option>" +
             "<option value='Cheetah'>Cheetah</option>" +
             "<option value='Spotted Hyena'>Spotted Hyena</option>" +
             "<option value='Wild Dogs'>Wild Dogs</option>" +
             "<option value='Hippo'>Hippo</option>" +
             "<option value='Kudu'>Kudu</option>" +
             "<option value='Zebra'>Zebra</option>" +
             "<option value='Fish Eagle'>Fish Eagle</option>" +
             "<option value='Other'>Other</option>" +
             "</select> </td></tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Description:</td> <td><input type='text' id='description'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";


infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
}

function saveData() {
  var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
  var time = escape(document.getElementById("time").value);
  var sighting = escape(document.getElementById("sighting").value);
  var description = escape(document.getElementById("description").value);

  var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&time=" + time +
  "&sighting=" + sighting + "&description" + description + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Then this in the body

```
<div id="map">
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 950px; height: 534px"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

And this is my PHP

```
    <?php
    require("phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php");

    // Gets data from URL parameters
    $name = $_GET['map_client_name'];
    $time = $_GET['client_time'];
    $lat = $_GET['client_lat'];
    $lng = $_GET['client_lng'];
    $description = $_GET['client_description'];
    $sighting = $_GET['client_sighting'];


    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection = mysql_connect ("mysql.spri.co.za", "sean_sql", "Paaseiers01");
    if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }


   // Set the active MySQL database
   $db_selected = mysql_select_db($kruger_park_live, $connection);
   if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
   }

   // Insert new row with user data
   $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_maps " .
         " (ID, map_client_name, client_time, client_lat, client_lng, client_description, 

   client_sighting) " .
         " VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
         mysql_real_escape_string($name),
         mysql_real_escape_string($time),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
         mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
         mysql_real_escape_string($description),
         mysql_real_escape_string($sighting));

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
```

Could someone please help me, I have been going at this for 4 days and I have just given up now. Thank you very much

Comment: Can we have the code of `downloadUrl()` in JS, and whether you can see the request in the **Network** tab of the debug console of your browser?

Comment: Why are you passing in `null` in `request.send(null)`? I've never seen that before, don't think it will mess anything up but who knows. Also if you have jquery on the site I would just use $.ajax [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make your call so you don't have to worry about browser compatibility.

Comment: If you see that the request is going through start stepping through your php script. It's hard to use `die()` statements since it is script being called by ajax, but one sluething approach that works good in this situation is to use php's [mail](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to email yourself the results of your test so you can tell if the correct data is getting transmitted and parsed.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld  - This code is given on the Google developers site. It is the first time I am trying to do something like this. I copied the code and made my changes. I dont have code for downloadURL

Comment: @Mike problem is the request is not going through or at least it doesn't seem to be

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3#CreatingTable

Comment: Start adding some alerts in the downloadUrl function to make sure you are making it there, so something like `alert("made it");` right at the beginning of the function then more as you go down to see where it is failing if you are even making it. Also you may want to move the declaration of the `var request` variable to all one line so `var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :new XMLHttpRequest;`

Comment: You need to eliminate where the error occurs. First. Hard code data ($name="name")Etc. in PHP file to ensure INSERT query works. Second.If INSERT works manually create URL and see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The code below use [**jQuery**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to send data to php file, and return data if succesful, in place of `downloadUrl()`

Include

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your head

```
function saveData() {
     var latlng = marker.getPosition();
     var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
     var time = escape(document.getElementById("time").value);
     var sighting = escape(document.getElementById("sighting").value);
     var description = escape(document.getElementById("description").value);
     $.get('phpsqlinfo_addrow.php',{lat:latlng.lat(),lng:latlng.lng(),name:name,time:time,sighting:sighting,description:description})
     .done(function(data){  
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
     });    
    }
```

**NOT REQUIRED**

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback)
```

and

```
function doNothing() {}
```

The next code uses [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) in place of the deprecated `mysql_` functions

phpsqlinfo_addrow.php

```
require("dbinfo.php");// database connections
// Get parameters from URL
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lng = $_GET["lng"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$time = $_GET["time"];
$description = $_GET["description"];
$sighting = $_GET["sighting"];
//Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare INSERT statement new sigting
        $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_maps (ID, map_client_name, client_time, client_lat, client_lng, client_description, client_sighting)  VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        // Assign parameters
        $stmt3->bindParam(1,$name);
        $stmt3->bindParam(2,$time);
        $stmt3->bindParam(3,$lat);
        $stmt3->bindParam(4,$lng);
        $stmt3->bindParam(5,$description);
        $stmt3->bindParam(6,$sighting);
        $stmt3->execute();
        $data[] = array("name"=>$name, "lat"=>round($lat,6), "lng"=>round($lng,6),"time"=>$time,"description"=>$description,"sighting"=>$sighting);
        //Data for success
        echo json_encode($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Message.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", phpsqlinfo_addrow.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much for the help. It seems to be working but there is one more small error. On click and save I get the following error. Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in <b>/home/sea502/public_html/krugerparklive/dbinfo.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />

Comment: Line 23 is $stmt->execute(); the code is listed above in @davidstrachan

Comment: @davidstrachen i think i am confused here and using the wrong code in the wrong place

Comment: if i upload the the the phpsqlinfo_addrow.php file that you gave me and click on save and close I get the following <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require(dbinfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/sean/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require(dbinfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/sean/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require(): Failed opening required 'dbinfo.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')

Comment: then i changed that file name to dbinfo.php and got the out of memory error.

Comment: Hi. It is still giving the error that it is to big I tried to ask my server to increaae the size but thdey cant. Anything i can do

Comment: dbinfo.php `<?php  
$host= "localhost";
$username="XXX";
$password="XXX";
$database="XXX";
?>
WHERE XXX is your details`

Comment: @davidstrachen, it seems to be sending the info now but then times out, giving me this error; Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', NULL, NULL)
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: I have tried to specify TCP/IP by adding port but i get the same error

Comment: It looks like your parameters in new `PDO()`are not there. TRY hardcoding ie `new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tablename", "username", "password");` where tablename, username & password are your details.